# VS Setup Project: Add Start Menu link to a file in a Merge Module

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project, merge-module

I have created a new Visual Studio Setup Project that uses the output of another Merge Module project. The Merge Module contains files that will be installed into the "x:\program files\\Documentation". One of these files is "documentation.pdf". I would like to add a link to the Start Menu in the Setup Project to the documentation PDF. The problem is that the Setup Project will not allow you "Create Shortcut" to files that are not physically in the setup project. I don't see a way to look or link into the Merge Module.

I also can't seem to find a way to create a generic smart menu location that will be renamed in the Merge Module. An example would be like all files in the "Module Retargetable Folder" will be redirected to the "Installation Folder". I would like to do the same thing with the start menu.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Merge Modules. Moving project to InstallShield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that this can't be done.